# Solution to avoid hard coding python

Tags: python

I want a solution to avoid hard coding in this if condition of my python script:

```
if (x.get('name')=='location'):
```

this is to be used for extracting the location tag from an xml file . user must modify this according to the xml file being used.
so what i must do ?

Comment: Use a conf file, use command line arguments, the sky is the limit.

Answer (score 0):

```
check_tag = raw_input("Enter the tag you wish to search for: ")

if (x.get('name')==check_tag):
```

use `input()` instead of `raw_input()` if using python 3

Comment: You are assuming OP is using Python 2. `raw_input` doesn't exist in Python 3.